# React JS: How to take the specific data and put it in a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, google-maps

I have a separate file with some data:

```
module.export = {
    city1 : {
        name: 'Peshawar, Pakistan',
        image: '',
        about: 'World Health Organization has ranked Peshawar as the second most...'
    },
    city2: {
        name: 'Handan, China',
        image: '',
        about: 'Hebei province, home to many of China’s most polluted cities, has  promised to...'
    },
    city3: {
        name: 'Lucknow, India',
        image: '',
        about: 'Lucknow faces many problems similar to major metros in India. So...'
    },
}
```

And I want to, for example, on a click of a Marker (from Google Maps API) to show city1 data (or whichever is clicked) in a separate component. How do I do that?

Comment: You have to find a way to link your markers with the cities and then when a user click on a marker, just filter your exported object to retrieve only the right city.

Comment: Do you have your project on Github or somewhere else where we could take a look at the code?

Comment: No, not yet. Basically, I installed Google maps api:  https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/ and i added some markers like <Marker>{Some City}</Marker and onClick i want the data above to appear in another page.

Answer (score -1):

Do you use an npm package? This one might be useful to you:
https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/

You will need to dispatch an action when a user clicks on a marker and then handle this action in a Reducer (if you use Redux.)

Comment: the question is more about props usage and data propagation than map component problem o react stack.

Comment: I did use that package and it works fine. I just want to connect Markers from that map to the data above and present it in a separate component

Comment: Can you not dispatch an action when someone clicks on a marker?

Comment: I don't use redux, it's not necessary.